# Mapfragment is not loaded within fragment the second time

Tags: android, supportmapfragment

MapFragment is not loaded within fragment the second time. I have tried to change some code within override methods but still it's not working. And I'm implementing these interfaces

```
OnMapReadyCallback,     
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,  
GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
LocationListener,
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
```

Here is the code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_new1, container, false);

        FragmentManager manager =getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.map, fragment);
        transaction.commit();

        shared = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // value_latLan=new ArrayList<>();

        app_bar = (CoordinatorLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        layoutCartNoItems = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_cart_empty);
        hv = (HorizontalScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.hv);
        l11 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.l1);
        l2 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.l2);

        // fragment.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        l11.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#dddddd"));
        hv.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        //  app_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // getActivity().getActionBar().hide();

        l11.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        layoutCartNoItems.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
        fragment.getMapAsync(this);

    return view;
}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
      //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    mGoogleMap=googleMap;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Location Permission already granted
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            //Request Location Permission
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What do you mean by second time? Are you relaunching same fragment or what

Comment: Yes, am relaunching the same fragment but displaying only white screen

Comment: How you are relaunching your fragment

Comment: I just go to the previous activity and then click on  a button that will move to the fragment

Comment: Did you wrote any code in onResume?

Comment: yes.   @Override
    public void onResume(){
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
        super.onResume();
    }

Comment: Do you have this code on github repo?

Comment: We can chat here - https://join.skype.com/JeEkFZpT6xkq

Comment: Yes, I have that code on github

Comment: Actually i have changed lot of codes in the source code so not exactly same as the github source code

Comment: Your code is pushed on github?

Comment: No, my code is not pushed on github